# How do I prevent all buttons from getting clicked in a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

So, I want to show some details when I click the details button. I have used for loop to loop through the buttons but it makes it so that when I click a single button, rest of the buttons get clicked as well. I understand it happens because of the for loop. But how do I make all the buttons clickable using a loop but prevent all of them from getting clicked when I click one?
I'm super new to JavaScript.

```
  function showDetails() {
    for (let i = 0; i < allProducts.length; i++) {
      const getHiddenDescription = document.getElementsByClassName("details");
      getHiddenDescription[i].style = "display: block";
      console.log("clicked");
    }
  }
  const getDetails = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-details");
  for (let i = 0; i < allProducts.length; i++) {
    getDetails[i].addEventListener("click", showDetails);
  }
```

Comment: you can use id to select your buttons. Otherwise, ıt will effect all your buttons.

Comment: Why is this tagged CSS & HTML?

Comment: You must use `this` to refer to the clicked item. In this way, you will only click on the clicked item and not on the other buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the button which triggered the event listener by using an optional parameter available in the event listener callback, often named `event`, like so.

```
function showDetails(event) {
 clickedButton = event.currentTarget;
 clickedbutton.style = "display: block";
}
```